# Which reasons are there to use Super Saiyan God instead of Super Saiyan Blue?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

From japanese magazines, dragon ball super staff twitter accounts and Dragon Ball Super episode 104th preview we know that,

> Goku is going to use Super Saiyan God again                                 [image]

Which advantages does it have using Super Saiyan God instead of Super Saiyan Blue?

Comment: When I read the manga it was given that super saiyan red uses less stamina than super saiyan blue. But seeing as this will happen in the next episode for some reason or another, Goku will probably give an explanation why he uses that form.

Comment: I believe so. I'm not sure if the manga explanations count for the anime, may be they do, some people says they are different continuities. But from the anime there are details about super saiyan god. For example one thing it was shown in the anime it is super saiyan god has regeneration "wolverine like" abilities. Now some people is saying super saiyan god could be faster? I dont know where this idea could come from . I havent seen any reason in the anime to think so, other than Goku gets thinner when he becomes super saiyan god

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Manga, Goku and Vegeta both thought up methods to conserve stamina when using SSB. They demonstrated these in their fight against Zamasu. Vegetas in particular is what we want, but understanding both is important.

Goku, in chapter 24, around page 33, sealed his power in his body. By doing so, the SSB aura disappeared. This is exactly what what he and Gohan did in the Hyperbolic time chamber for SSJ 1. The aura they release costs them power, draining stamina. By containing that aura in their body, they reduced the stamina drain down to almost nil, and so were able to stay transformed for extended periods of time. Goku replicated this with SSB, and so it can drain little stamina to keep active. As Vegeta put in, he was "fighting at a constant 100% of his power". He was able to fight on near equal footing with Fused Zamasu for a while at least.

Vegeta had a different solution, one that I think addresses the question quite nicely, albeit indirectly. On the same page as the quote I just said from Vegeta, he also noted "the fact that its only able to output full power for a very short time is blues greatest weakness". Vegeta's solution to this was displayed a few chapters earlier. In chapter 22, around page 15, Vegeta transformed into SSG, the Red form. He then revealed that that was his answer to the stamina problem. Red drains far less stamina than Blue, and so he used Red which he had mastered (He managed to contain the aura like Goku did for Blue), and then would transform into blue right as he attacked for an instant. His attacks had all the power of Blue, but the stamina drain of Blue was only in effect for an instant at a time, so he could maintain his max power for longer.

So, why is Goku using SSG, probably because its his most powerful form that doesn't cut his power in half after a minute of use. He has not mastered Blue yet in the anime that we know of, but it is known that the Aura they release when transformed is a huge drain on stamina. Red just drains less than Blue.

Comment: Do we know how close the Manga and Anime are correlated on issues such as this? I mean, the Manga and Anime both used Zen-Oh to deal with Zamasu, but the conditions of the world pre-calling him were diferent (multiple Zamasu's as opposed to Zamasu-sky) and I don't think the anime ever discussed stamina problems (which you'd assume they'd do to buy runtime on the show).

Nevertheless, gets an upvote from me as it's a very logical answer. Plus, it allows me the hope of seeing Vegeta in SSG in the anime.

Comment: @Philbo As I have heard, there is an outline written by Toriyama given to both of them, and then they fill in the details independently. The anime takes far more liberties regarding breaking continuity for a show, but there is no way Vegeta was significantly weaker than Goku when they fought Hit  (excluding KaioKen) unless it was stamina related. They both set that up, so it was probably part of that outline. The anime does what it wants though, so its impossible to predict what they will do. Blue+KaioKen as an example, because that and Hits power levels make no sense.